# How to give xsd schema present in WAR file in beans.xml?

Tags: xml, jboss, xsd, war, weblogic12c

My xsd files are in the directory, \WEB-INF\xsd-file. How do I refer this path in beans.xml? I tried this but I am getting "Failed to read schema document '/WEB-INF/xsd_files/spring-beans-2.5.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .>"

Currently I have tried like this:

> xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
>   /WEB-INF/xsd_files/spring-beans-2.5.xsd   http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
>   /WEB-INF/xsd_files/jaxws.xsd
>     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
>   /WEB-INF/xsd_files/spring-context-3.0.xsd" >